# Problem using service accounts in gke deployment

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, service-accounts

I have a service account created in terraform. I want to use it to deploy a workload using a docker image stored in artifacts.

```
resource "google_service_account" "artifact_reader" {
 account_id = "artifact-reader" 
 display_name = "Artifact Reader Service Account for Deployments"

 project = var.project_id 
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "artifact_reader_binding" {
 project = var.project_id
 role = "roles/editor" 

 members = [
 "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.artifact_reader.email}"
 ]
}
```

it creates a service which can be viewed with `gcloud iam service-accounts describe` and give the result:

```
displayName: Artifact Reader Service Account for Deployments
email: artifact-reader@as1.iam.gserviceaccount.com
etag: MDEwMjE5MjA=
name: projects/as1/serviceAccounts/artifact-reader@as1.iam.gserviceaccount.com
oauth2ClientId: '116283672136579491873'
projectId: as1
uniqueId: '116283672136579491873'
```

so far so good...

my yaml file contains the Stateful Set definition:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
 name: my-ssh
 labels:
 app: ssh
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
 matchLabels:
 app: ssh
 template:
 metadata:
 labels:
 app: ssh
 spec:
 serviceAccountName: artifact-reader@as1.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
 containers:
 - name: ssh 
 image: europe-north1-docker.pkg.dev/as1/bounce/bounce:latest
 ports:
 - containerPort: 22
```

But then during the deployment I am getting errors:

> create Pod my-ssh-0 in StatefulSet my-ssh failed error: pods
> "my-ssh-0" is forbidden: error looking up service account
> default/artifact-reader@as1.iam.gserviceaccount.com: serviceaccount
> "artifact-reader@as1.iam.gserviceaccount.com" not found

I am guessing the "default/" is the namespace but I was not modifying the namespaces anywhere in the yaml file or while creating the service account so both the service account and the deployments should be  in the same namespace(?). I also tried creating another service account, inside the yaml file, but then it does not have the permissions for the artifacts repo and also ends with errors.
I am missing some piece of a puzzle here. How can I make the deployment succeed?

Comment: Hi Chris, did you have the yaml definition the service account? Like apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount blablabla?

Comment: i tried to define some service account in the yaml like below and use it. but then this service account has no iam permissions for the artifacts and it fails too. 
```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: servacc
```

Comment: If you defined your service account with the name servacc, then you need to use that name on your stateful set serviceAccountName

Comment: Maybe you are missing something like: kubectl annotate serviceaccount servacc \
    --namespace NAMESPACE \
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=GSA_NAME@GSA_PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's confusing but ...

Google (aka IAM) Service Accounts != Kubernetes Service Accounts.

You **cannot** use a Google (IAM) Service Account (`{account}@{project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) as a Kubernetes Service Account

There are various ways that you configure a Kubernetes Service Account to impersonate a Google (IAM) Service Account; effectively, A Google (IAM) Service Account becomes "twinned" with a Kubernetes Service Account.

The preferred mechanism is Workload Identity Federation (WIF). Although it's somewhat tortuous to enable|configure, it works very well and is an elegant solution.

See:

- [Workload Identity Federation for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/workload-identity)
- [About GKE (sic.) Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/service-accounts)

Comment: That looks like the way to go! It looks like I also need to define the  WIF workload provider. I saw some tuts for gitlab and WIF. In my case I just want to deploy the kubernetes on gcloud and use the artifacts in the process.  So in my case -  what is the issuer url and how do I generate the JWK file?

Comment: I included a link to [Workload Identity Federation for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/workload-identity) in my answer and here's a link to [Authenticate to Google APIs from GkE Workloads](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) which is linked from it. The documentation is comprehensive and accurate and I encourage you to try it out on a sacrificial cluster.

Answer (score 0):

**Potential issue:**

If a Kubernetes Service account is specified within the pod manifest it must exist in the same namespace where the pod is being deployed.

```
spec:
  serviceAccountName: KSA_NAME
```

**Diagnosis**

Inspect the logs using the below query at the time the issue happened

```
resource.type="k8s_cluster"
resource.labels.cluster_name="<Cluster_Name>"
log_name="projects/<Project>/logs/events"
severity=WARNING
```

You will find similar errors (Also you have mentioned in the question)

```
pods "xxx" is forbidden: error looking up service account default/xxx: serviceaccount "xxx" not found
```

This error message indicates that the service account is missing from the Pod's namespace. Therefore, you may create a Kubernetes Service Account in the same namespace as the pod

Comment: I am not sure about your SA configurations. but, this is purely based on my understanding.